# Running two services(each have their own subdomain name) on same server with Traefik proxy

Tags: docker, dns, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to run two separate API's on a local server, and point two different DNS A Records to the same server. Something like service1.userdomain.com => [ip address] and service2.userdomain.com => [ip address]

I thought I could use Traefik and route to two different docker images based on the host name. However this isnt working as I get a 504 Gateway timeout when trying to hit the service. The services themselves are listening to port :8080

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
      image: traefik:latest
      restart: always
      command:
        - --accesslog
        - --api.insecure=true
        - --providers.docker
        - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "8080:8080"
  service1:
    image: ghcr.io/user/service1:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - fullstack 
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.service1.rule=Host(`service1.domain.com`)
  service2:
    image: ghcr.io/user/serice2:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "8082:8080"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.service2.rule=Host(`service2.domain.com`)
    networks:
      - fullstack 

networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Are you able to get one service working?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I ended up getting one service working and then was able to add two. I didnt quite have the correct dockerfile and the docker compose for traefik wasnt correct. I just took this https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/ and modified it for multiple services. Thanks for the suggestion